# VS 2008 doesnot have Sql Server Express 2005 x64 in prerequisite dialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, setup-deployment, prerequisites

I am trying to install a VS 2008 application on a 64 bit system. All works fine but Sql Server Express 2005 fails because in prerequisite dialog it only offer x86 version and no x64 version.

So what should I install instead of that ? Should I directly download sql server express 2005 x64 version from Microsoft website and redistribute it ?

Regards
Niraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there really isn't any reason why the application has to be 64-bit (memory usage or whatever), then just force a 32-bit build and be done with it. Most "normal" applications should not have any trouble running as 32-bit apps on a 64-bit OS.

In other words, set Platform Target in Project Properties/Build/ to *x86* and make sure to set Configuration to *All Configurations*.

I realize that this doesn't really answer your question but it could solve your problem.

Comment: Hi dandan78,Thanks for the reply, yes the purpose is only to run the application successfully on the 64-bit system.

Comment: In that case the above solution should work for you. I had to do this in the case of an app that was interacting with 32-bit code, which didn't cause any problems on 32-bit Windows, but resulted in crashes on 64-bit Win because of the Any CPU setting. As a result, the .Net runtime was switching the app to 64-bit and when it tried to access the 32-bit code, bad things would happen. Forcing x86 put a stop to that.